# How to disable the translate option of content in TYPO3 8.7 translation wizard?

Tags: typo3

In TYPO3 8.7 you can choose whether you want to translate or copy content elements. How can I disable the "translate" option in the first step of the wizard?

In a current project the customer prefers to have only the copy possibility.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Core itself supports this starting with version 9, so there is currently no core-wise solution in 8.x.

But: You may write an extension supporting the same configuration parameters as v9 does by XClassing PageLayoutView.php. Please [see the change](https://review.typo3.org/52345) that introduces the possibility to configure these buttons.

Comment: Thx for the hint! I feared that there is no solution. I'll go for the XClassing solution now.

Comment: So there is no core option to have a reasonable translate functionality in 8.7 LTS? It seems that dialog does not make much sense regarding sys_page_overlay config and BOTH buttons available in the dialog. I'm confused.

Comment: The point is that this behaviour might and is allowed to differ between combinations of pages and languages. The default behaviour - especially when using the Localization Manager Extensions - would be to "translate" everything into the so called "connected" mode, while copying things into the "free" mode would be the exception.

Still there might be scenarios where depending on your preferred mode you still need the other mode for a certain language or a certain page, since they might use special additional content (for connected mode) or automated translation (for free mode).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Joey! The general concept seems very useful and logical but I don't understand how to use this in the real world with the current LTS version. My main issue is when I'm using `config.sys_language_overlay = 1` the copy mode will not work but if I disable it, the translate mode will not work. Can you explain how to configure the TS in oder to make this work?

Comment: Xclass for TYPO3 8.7 by @PeterKraume
https://gist.github.com/peterkraume/1c0feb30440449ba1c708aa5ea8d7991

Answer (score 2):

Thx to the hint from Andreas Fernandez I was able to backport the feature from TYPO3 9.x to 8.7.x by xclassing the method.

I've put everything together into a Gist:
https://gist.github.com/peterkraume/1c0feb30440449ba1c708aa5ea8d7991

Answer (score 2):

I am just using a css-based solution.

Just add the following to "ext_tables.php"

```
// Custom Backend CSS
$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['skins']['base'] = [
    'name' => 'cytrus Base Backend Skin',
    'stylesheetDirectories' => ['EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Backend/']
];
```

And then create a file "mycss.css" in "EXT:myext/Resources/Public/Backend/" with the following content:

```
[data-slide="localize-choose-action"] > div > div:first-child {display: none;}
```

that's it!

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu1dl.jpg)